# Portal 2 will not launch on windows 10, but the CD version will

Tags: steam, portal-2

I have portal 2 on a cd that I just found. At first, the CD was not working, so I bought it off of steam. After fiddling with the steam version for what feels like 5-6 hours, i have done the following:
Verified Cache several times
Deleted the program, reinstalled, and then verified cache
Reinstalled Directx
Reinstalled vcredist, both x86 and x64
Run as administrator
Run as a normal user
Run as an administrator with compatibility set to windows 7
Run as a normal user with compatability mode set to windows 7
Run as an administrator with compatibility set to windows 8
Run as a normal user with compatability mode set to windows 8
Run as windowed through steam
Uninstalled GPU drivers with DDU and reinstalled
Uninstalled steam and reinstalled
Tried different resolutions

Portal continues to either load to the picture of chell and glados and then crash, or fullscreens and stays on a black screen after the startup sound.

I have the CD working now, and it works perfect, but I cannot update it to get the level editor.
At this point, can anyone think of what the issue may be?

Windows 10
AMD A10-6800K
16GB RAM
MSI GTX 980

Comment: Remove Portal 2 , restart PC then Re-install Portal 2. maybe you want to delete all portal 2 registry (CCleaner) just for caution.

Comment: @NamikazeSheena How should I remove it? Manually, etc

Comment: just use uninstaller from control panel

or right click Portal 2 from steam and choose remove local files

Comment: @NamikazeSheena That did not work. I'm beginning to think that it's a nvidia issue, as many people with nvidia cards have this issue. As I stated, I have windows 10. As a result, only a few Nvidia drivers are supported. Trying to install older drivers results in a failure, as nvidia has made the installers fail because it's not the correct version of windows.

Comment: @NamikazeSheena That also did not work. Please note that most souce games don't work. Portal 1 does the same thing, along with CS:GO and garry's mod.

Comment: wheatley 2.0 asks: "have u checked if you have space on your computer"

Comment: I ask: Can you get a crash report?